# Same methods for similar Pages with different xpaths page object model pytest python

Tags: python, selenium, pytest, pom.xml, pageobjects

I'm currently working on an automation project using the pom framework and pytest. In my application, I have many pages with similar designs. However, I have to create unique methods for each page because they have unique Ids and paths. Kindly advise if is there a better way to design rather than creating a unique method for each page?
I'm creating a lot of the same methods to maintain the POM framework design.
Below is a sample code that is being used to select data in a grid and it is present on multiple pages.

```
 def select_transactions(self,count,*txntype):
        length1 = self.count_matching_element(cal.ca_txt_mtch)
        length2 = len(txntype)
        flag = 0
        temp = ""
        for j in range(0,length2):
            for i in range(0,length1):
                if txntype[j] != "ANY" :
                    xpath = self.update_xpath(cal.ca_txt_txntype, "param", str(i))
                    temp = self.get_text(xpath)
                    if txntype[j] == temp:
                        flag = flag + 1
                        f_xpath = self.update_xpath(cal.ca_chk_select, "param", str(i))
                        self.do_click(f_xpath)
                        if flag == count:
                            return str(i)
                            break
                else:
                    flag = flag + 1
                    f_xpath = self.update_xpath(cal.ca_chk_select, "param", str(i))
                    self.do_click(f_xpath)
                    if flag == count:
                        return str(i)
                        break
```

Comment: Well, create a class that will have all the utils method, and call them whenever you need 'em. This looks more of OOP, inheritance issue.

Comment: @cruisepandey how to pass xpath of different pages which are using same utils method, should I declare all the element in arguments, is there any other way?